# Python find out duplicates in array using function

Tags: python

Example 1:
input: [1,3,2,1,3,5]

Output: [1,3]

```
def duplicateNumber(mylist):
??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Next time at least make an honest effort, describe the problem you are facing and then ask a question :

```
 def duplicateNumber(x): 
        _size = len(x) 
        repeated = [] 
        for i in range(_size): 
            k = i + 1
            for j in range(k, _size): 
                if x[i] == x[j] and x[i] not in repeated: 
                    repeated.append(x[i]) 
        return repeated
```

Comment: Don't answer questions that are clear duplicates (and low effort).